# An urn contains $n$ red and $n$ blue balls. If two balls are drawn at random from the urn, what is the probability they have different colors?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

An urn contains n red and n blue balls. Two balls are drawn from the urn together, at random. What is the probability that two balls of different colors are drawn?

My approach:

The space room is:

$\Omega $ ={(r,b),(b,b),(r,r)}  with r="red ball" and b="blue ball"

How do I calculate now the probability I'm looking for?

Is it:

$\mathbb{P}((r,b))$ = $ \frac{1}{2n}*\frac{1}{2n}=\frac{1}{4n^2} $ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many balls are there? $2n$ right? . So in how many ways can you possibly choose two balls from it? . You can do it by $\binom{2n}{2}$.  But if you want the two balls two be different. Then you choose one ball out of $n$ red ball by $\binom{n}{1}$ and another one simultaneously from $n$ blue balls by $\binom{n}{1}$ . So the probability is $\frac{\binom{n}{1}\cdot\binom{n}{1}}{\binom{2n}{2}}=\frac{n}{2n-1}$.

Alternatively you can try to substract from $1$ , the probability of getting both balls of same colour to get the same answer. i.e. $1-2\cdot \frac{\binom{n}{2}}{\binom{2n}{2}}=\frac{n}{2n-1}$